# Event propagation confusion

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an element nested in another element. I have a `mouseover` event registered on the outer element. It fires both when my mouse enters the outer element, and when it enters the inner element. How can I turn off the event firing on the inner element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events fire on objects then bubble up the DOM tree. But you can stop them from bubbling with `event.stopPropagation()`. This only works on standards-compliant browsers (not all but the most recent versions of IE).

```
innerElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

IE's version will be:

```
innerElement.attachEvent('onmouseover', function () {
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
});
```

So altogether:

```
function listener(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
if (innerElement.addEventListener) {
    innerElement.addEventListener('mouseover', listener, false);
} else {
    innerElement.attachEvent('onmouseover', listener);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
el.onmouseover = function(e) {
  //normalize event object to avoid cross browser inconsistencies
  e = e || window.event;

  //grab target element from which event is originated
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (target === el) {
    //do something here
  }
};
```

If you use jQuery() it offers nice .hover() event which will handle such problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn it off, but your handler can always check `event.target` (or `event.srcElement` on IE) to make sure that it pertains to the correct one.

Alternatively, you can add a handler to the inner element and have it call "stopPropagation()" on the event object.